# How can I have static dispatch for a linked list containing different types all implementing a trait?

Tags: generics, linked-list, rust, static-dispatch

I have this working code:

```
struct Layer<'a> {
    parent: Option<Box<Layer<'a>>>,
    value: Box<dyn Renderable + 'a>,
}
```

I would like to have a version using static dispatch instead:

```
struct Layer<'a, R: Renderable> {
    parent: Option<&'a Layer<'a, /* ? */>>,
    value: R,
}
```

The type replacing the question mark implements `Renderable`, but it's not necessarily `R`, it could be `T: Renderable` for example. I would like to avoid any solution using `dyn Renderable`, to keep the static dispatch.

The type `T: Renderable` is known at `Layer` instantiation and won't change.

Comment: If you want heterogeneous lists then you'll inevitably end up with a bunch of type parameters. Take for example, Frunk, which manages to accomplish this, but makes compilation times exceedingly slow, and the memory usage during compilation is large. If you want a heterogeneous list, with the same type as another list whose types it contains are different, then you cannot do this without dynamic dispatch, or enums.

Comment: You most likely cannot replace `Box` in your first example with `&'a` in your next, since linked lists are unpleasant in rust code. They also don't vectorise properly, and can lead to alot of inefficiencies, which would make your `dyn` vs not problem moot.

Comment: Another question is why have you decided to architect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It is impossible (at least w/o [variadic generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/376)*)

- Right now `Layer` structure requires `2` generic parameters: `R` and `'a`.
- Let's imagine we found the right type for `/* ? */`. Let's name it `T0`.
- Then `Layer` structure will require `3` generic parameters: `T0`, `R` and `'a`.
- Then you have to provide one more generic parameter for `parent` field. Let's name it `T1`.
- Then `Layer` structure will require `4` generic parameters: `T1`, `T0`, `R` and `'a`.
- Then you have to provide one more generic parameter for `parent` field. Let's name it `T2`.
- <...>
- Then `Layer` structure will require `i+2` generic parameters: `Ti`, `Ti-1`, ... `T1`, `T0`, `R` and `'a`.
- Then you have to provide one more generic parameter for `parent` field. Let's name it `Ti+1`.
- Then `Layer` structure will require `i+1+2` generic parameters: `Ti+1`, `Ti`, `Ti-1`, ... `T1`, `T0`, `R` and `'a`.
- <...>

At the end, you have infinite recursion. Additional generic parameter for `parent` field have to be defined as a part of `Layer` structure. That induce introduction of a new generic parameter for `Layer`. That induce additional generic parameter for `parent` field.

To break up recursion, additional generic parameter for `parent` shouldn't be  a part of `Layer` definition. If a parameter is not a part of `Layer` definition then we can't calculate `Layer` size at compile time. The way it may be solved is `&dyn` or `Box`.

*The other possible solution is [variadic generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/376) but it looks like we will not have it at least for next few months or even years.